# Batch saving Multiple Layers on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, batch, save

I have 24 layers I want to save on QGIS which all happen to be Tiff files (rasters).  I am wondering how to run code to complete this task.

```
myDir = 'C:\temp'
layers = layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter("%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() ))
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
```

This is the code I have currently to try and run.

Comment: And what happens when you run it? :)

Comment: @Joseph an error could be  `file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + layer.name() + ".tif")`with a missing "\" I would use  `QgsRasterFileWriter("%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() ))` instead

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'extent'

Comment: @Jhunt9 replace `layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()`with `layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()`

Comment: It computes it as True.  But now I dont see anything in the place where I sent it to.  I'm a noobie coder sorry.  I changed to location saved to myDir = 'C:\temp' and it isnt going to it.

Comment: @Jhunt9 it seems you updated the wrong code? for the location see my first comment

Comment: I did update that code.  I currently have what I originally posted.  Sorry about that.  As I said it computes as True but I still cannot find the files.

Comment: @Jhunt9 - Could you add `print "%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() )` inside your loop to see exactly what the paths look like?

Comment: Is it possible that an escape sequence is ruining your path? Try: myDir = r'C:\temp' --> \t is an escape sequence

Comment: I put the Print inside the loop and it computed to this >>>  print "%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() )
   
True
True
0
C: emp\o4670c.tif
True
True
0
C: emp\o4569b.tif

Comment: Yes! The escape charater got you! --> http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myDir = r'C:\temp'
layers = layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
    extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter("%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() ))
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
   print "%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() )
```

This is the Code that worked!
Thank you @LaughU, @AndreasK, & @Joseph